# C# Read and parse all xml files in directory directory and write to signle csv file

Tags: c#, xml, csv, parsing

i have the same structure for many xml files inside a directory.

I want to write a single csv file with elements needed.

Im totally new in this world, can u help me please? i need a recursive method?
i need to read  and not all

```
<DatiBeniServizi> // Descendants
        <DettaglioLinee>
            <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
            <CodiceArticolo>
                <CodiceTipo>AswArtFor</CodiceTipo> // <- i dont need this
                <CodiceValore>312</CodiceValore> // <- i need only this
            </CodiceArticolo>
            <Descrizione>DELL LATITUDE E6440  CORE I5 4300 2.7 GHZ  8 GB RAM HD 320 DVD WIN 10 PRO GARANZIA 6 MESI</Descrizione>
            <Quantita>5.00000000</Quantita>
            <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
            <PrezzoUnitario>180.00000000</PrezzoUnitario>
            <PrezzoTotale>900.00000000</PrezzoTotale>
            <AliquotaIVA>0.00</AliquotaIVA>
            <Natura>N6</Natura>
        </DettaglioLinee>
        <DettaglioLinee>
            <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>
            <CodiceArticolo>
                <CodiceTipo>AswArtFor</CodiceTipo> // <- i dont need this
                <CodiceValore>499</CodiceValore> // <- i need only this
            </CodiceArticolo>
            <Descrizione>DELL OPTIPLEX 7010 TOWER i7-3770 3.40 GHz HD 250 GB RAM 4 GB GARANZIA  6 MESI</Descrizione>
            <Quantita>3.00000000</Quantita>
            <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
            <PrezzoUnitario>160.00000000</PrezzoUnitario>
            <PrezzoTotale>480.00000000</PrezzoTotale>
            <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
        </DettaglioLinee>
```

Im using this code but i cant read child

```
        var results = xDocument.Descendants("DatiBeniServizi").Select(x => new {
         Codice = (string)x.Element("CodiceValore"), 
         Descrizione = (string)x.Element("Descrizione"),
         Quantita = (string)x.Element("Quantita"),
         PrezzoUnitario = (string)x.Element("PrezzoUnitario"),
         AliquotaIVA = (string)x.Element("AliquotaIVA")
     }).ToList();

     for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
     {
         string tempCodice = results[i].Codice;
         string tempDescrizione = results[i].Descrizione;
         string tempQuantita =results[i].Quantita;
         string tempprezzoUnitario = results[i].PrezzoUnitario;
         string tempAliquotaIVA = results[i].AliquotaIVA;

         dataToBeWritten.Append(tempCodice);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
         dataToBeWritten.Append(tempDescrizione);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
         dataToBeWritten.Append(tempQuantita);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
         dataToBeWritten.Append(tempprezzoUnitario);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
         dataToBeWritten.Append(tempAliquotaIVA);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
         dataToBeWritten.Append(0);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(";");
         dataToBeWritten.Append(0);
         dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);
     }


     Console.WriteLine(dataToBeWritten.ToString());
     Console.ReadLine();

     var testpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\test.csv";

     File.WriteAllText(testpath, dataToBeWritten.ToString());
```

" Codice = (string)x.Element("CodiceValore"), " // <- i can't read this, i can read only

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach but i don't know how to use, i know is ridicolous..

```
public class Articolo
    {
        public varID codici { get; set; }
        public string varDescrizione { get; set; }
        public string varPrezzoUnitario { get; set; }
        public int varQuantita { get; set; }
        public string varAliquotaIVA { get; set; }

    }

    public class varID
    {
        public List<codicearticolo>  codice = new List<codicearticolo>();

    }

    public class codicearticolo
    {
        public string varcodicetipo { get; set; }
        public string varcodicevalore { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Articolo> GetArticoloList()
    {
        //This method converts an xml file into a .csv file

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"c:\ft\test.xml");
        StringBuilder dataToBeWritten = new StringBuilder();

        var results = from x in xDocument.Descendants("DatiBeniServizi")
                      select new Articolo
                      {
                          codici = new varID()
                          {
                              codice = new List<codicearticolo>(from code in x.Descendants("CodiceArticolo")
                                                                    select new codicearticolo
                                                                    {
                                                                        varcodicetipo = code.Element("CodiceTipo").Value,
                                                                        varcodicevalore = code.Element("CodiceValore").Value

                                                                    })
                          },
                          varDescrizione = x.Element("Descrizione").Value,
                          varPrezzoUnitario = x.Element("PrezzoUnitario").Value,
                         varQuantita  = Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("Quantita").Value),
                          varAliquotaIVA = x.Element("AliquotaIVA").Value


                      };

            return results.ToList();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods from System.Xml.XPath.Extensions to do this.

For example, if you want to select a single element, you would use XPathSelectElement():

```
var element = xDocument.XPathSelectElement("/DatiBeniServizi/DettaglioLinee/CodiceArticolo/CodiceValore");
```

or using your approach - you need to set full path

```
var results = xDocument.Descendants("DatiBeniServizi").Select(x => new {
    Codice = (string)x.Elements("DettaglioLinee").Elements("CodiceArticolo").Elements("CodiceValore").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
    Descrizione = (string)x.Elements("DettaglioLinee").Elements("Descrizione").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
    Quantita = (string)x.Elements("DettaglioLinee").Elements("Quantita").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
    PrezzoUnitario = (string)x.Elements("DettaglioLinee").Elements("PrezzoUnitario").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
    AliquotaIVA = (string)x.Elements("DettaglioLinee").Elements("AliquotaIVA").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried yours solution but i got Exception ->  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: where are you seeing exception? i showed you only direction how to solve your issue. It is not completely working code.

Comment: U are my hero ! : thank you very much.... I had made the change only for the string, i am newbye.

Comment: the code works, but there are 2 articles in my example and there is only one article in result[i], why cant read others and put them in var result with this code? sorry man, i dont want to waste yours time

Comment: UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED, THANK YOU